# How to update an empty python dictionary by iterating over a word yielding like: {'letter in word':position of letter}?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to convert this string into a dictionary such that it produces a key-value pair where the Key is the alphabet and the Value is its corresponding position in the word: example

```
word = 'jazz'
word_dict = {'j':[0],'a':[1],'z':[2,3]}
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
        word = 'jazz'
        word_dict = {}
        for key, value in enumerate(word):
            dict_word = {value:key}
            print(dict_word)
```

The code above yeilds:

```
{'j': 0}
{'a': 1}
{'z': 2}
{'z': 3}
```

I am kind of stuck here and don't know how to proceed further so that I can update these outputs generated from the loop into a dictionary as mentioned above. I am kind of new to this so any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use a `defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

word = 'jazz'
word_dict = defaultdict(list)

for idx, chr in enumerate(word):
    word_dict[chr].append(idx)

print(word_dict)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list, {'j': [0], 'a': [1], 'z': [2, 3]})
```

The resulting `defaultdict` acts exactly like a real `dict`, but if you need it as a `dict` for some reason, you can call `dict(word_dict)`. However, everywhere where a `dict` will work, a `defaultdict` will work as it's a subclass.

Comment: thank you very much, this is more readable, appreciate your help!

Comment: However I am getting this error  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-237-ca20f0f4603c> in <module>()
----> 1 word_dict = defaultdict(list)
      2 
      3 for idx, char in enumerate(word):
      4     word_dict[char].append(idx)
      5 

TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Comment: @KarthikBhaktha You are getting this error because somewhere else in your code, you have a variable called `list`, overriding the built-in. Please check your variable names and try the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
word = 'jazz'
word_dict = {}

for key_as_value, value_as_key in enumerate(word):
    if value_as_key in word_dict:
        word_dict[value_as_key].append(key_as_value)
    else:
        word_dict[value_as_key] = [key_as_value]

print(word_dict)

# below is the output
{'j': [0], 'a': [1], 'z': [2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this working what you are looking for ?
Please check this code.

```
word = 'jazz'
word_dict = {}
for key, value in enumerate(word):
    dict_word = {value:key}
    word_dict.update(dict_word)
    print(dict_word)
print (word_dict)
```

Comment: unfortunately, it is not yielding the output I am looking for